# passing variables to bowtie from python

Tags: python

I want to pass an input fasta file stored in a variable say inp_a from python to bowtie and write the output into another out_a. I want to use 
os.system ('bowtie [options] inp_a out_a')
Can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks for two things, as far as I can tell: writing data to disk, and calling an external program from within Python. Without more detailed requirements, here's what I would write:

```
import subprocess

data_for_bowtie = "some genome data, lol"

with open("input.fasta", "wb") as input_file:
    input_file.write(data_for_bowtie)

subprocess.call(["bowtie", "input.fasta", "output.something"])
```

There are some fine details here which I have assumed. I'm assuming that you mean `bowtie`, the read aligner. I'm assuming that your file is a binary, non-human-readable one (which is why there's that `b` in the second argument to `open`) and I'm making baseless assumptions about how to call `bowtie` on the command line because I'm not motivated enough to spend the time learning it.

Hopefully, that provides a starting point. Good luck!